# Construct a DTO without explicitly naming values

Tags: javascript, json

I construct my DTO like this:

```
    var {a, b, c} = JSON.parse(response1)
    var otherObject = JSON.parse(response2)
    var dto = {
        a,
        b,
        c,
        otherObject
    };
```

I guess there is a smarter way to deconstruct `response1` without explicitly naming `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: *smarter* how exactly? Are there any other properties in `response1` other than `a`, `b`, `c`? Or, the properties names are dynamic and not always equal to `a`,`b`,`c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want **all** of the properties of `response1` in `dto`, you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const dto = {
    ...JSON.parse(response1),
    otherObject
};
```

Or [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const dto = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(response1));
dto.otherObject = otherObject;
// or
const dto = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(response1), {otherObject});
```

But if there are other things in there that you don't want in `dto`, you really only have three options:

- Listing the properties you want explicitly
- Listing the properties you don't want explicitly
- Using some kind of filter that may not have the explicit names of the properties, but can still identify them in *some* way to determine whether to add them to `dto` or not

Comment: For what it's worth, I go into spread syntax in detail in Chapters 5 and 6 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.